# Is it meaningful to compare a logit and probit model with the same no. of observations and independent variables using AIC and BIC?

Tags: aic, logit, probit, bic

For my dissertation i want to show that the logit and probit model produce the same results. So far i've compared the marginal effects, percent correctly predicted and done a scatter plot of the predicted probabilities. I also want to compare both models using aic and bic but is this worth doing since both models use the same no. of observations and independent variables?